# How to extract filenames and check if exists using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file `myfile.log` that looks like this:

```
 RS |         hello.txt|        OK|      INFO| [CATLG]
==============================================
 A4 |        byebye.txt|        OK|      INFO| [DELETE]
==============================================
Most common:
----------------------------------------------
 AS | stackoverflow.txt|        OK|      INFO| [CATLG]
```

Then I'm trying to create a script which extract the files which match with the regular expression:

```
\s(.+)\|\s+OK\|\s+INFO\|\s+\[CATLG
```

And finally check if the file exists on `/myfiles/record/` directory. If not, would be printed a D before the filename.

Here is an example of output supposing that `stackoverflow.txt` exists and `hello.txt` not exists:

```
  hello.txt
D stackoverflow.txt
```

I tried to use grep function, but if I do:

```
grep -oh '\s.+\|\s+OK\|\s+INFO\|\s+\[CATLG' myfile.log | uniq -i
```

Doesn't return nothing. What I doing wrong? Do you have any idea to do this?

Comment: You seem to have a _well-defined_ delimiter, `|`.  Consider using `awk` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep's regex doesn't support `\s` in regex. You can use `grep -P (PCRE)` flavor:

```
grep -oPh '\s.+\|\s+OK\|\s+INFO\|\s+\[CATLG' myfile.log
```

OR else translate your regex into ERE:

```
egrep -oh '[[:blank:]].+\|[[:blank:]]+OK\|[[:blank:]]+INFO\|[[:blank:]]+\[CATLG' myfile.log
```

To just print file names use:

```
grep -oPh '[^|]+\|\s+\K[^|]+(?=\|\s+OK.*?\[CATLG)' file
hello.txt
stackoverflow.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated again the structure of the file. I want to skip the first part of the line before the filename too. Why does not works `grep -Poh '(?=\s+\K).+(?=\|\s+OK\|\s+INFO\|\s+\[CATLG)' myfile.log | uniq -i` to my purpose? Thanks for all.

Comment: no, remove the first part of the line, in the case of hello.txt file: "RS |         " (see the new structure of the file in the first post). Thanks.

Comment: Great! And the final question (I promise): How I can exclude the files which contains an "AS" at the begin of the line? For example, in myfile.log would be excluded stackoverflow.txt. Thanks for your time, anubhava.

Comment: You can do: `grep -v ' *AS' file | grep -oPh '[^|]+\|\s+\K[^|]+(?=\|\s+OK.*?\[CATLG)'`

Comment: And the last one: how to excluding the files with ".jpg" extension? (if you answer this I'll adore you the rest of my life)

Comment: Try this: `grep -v ' *AS' file | grep -oPh '(?!.*?\.jpg)[^|]+\|\s+\K[^|]+(?=\|\s+OK.*?\[CATLG)'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '|' '/|/ {fname=gensub(" ","","g",$1)
                 if ( system( "[ -f " fname " ] " ) ) {
                 print "D " fname }
                 else {
                     print "  " fname }
           }' INPUTFILE
```

Might work for you.

1. sets the input field separator to `|`
2. work only on lines with `|`s
3. set the `fname` variable to the stripped version of the first field
4. call out to the test command (`[`) to the shell

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP '\|\s*\K\S+(?=\|\s+OK.*CATLG)' | 
while read file; do
    [[ -f /myfiles/record/"$file" ]] && flag="" || flag=D
    printf "%-2s%s\n" "$flag" "$file"
done
```

Explanation:

- The grep command uses (-P) perl regex syntax, and only outputs the matched text (-o), each match on its own line.

  - the `\K` directive means "forget about what just matched" -- it's a way to get a variable-length look-behind.
  - I'm finding non-space characters that are followed by: a pipe, whitespace, "OK", some chars, and "CATLG"
- The grep output is piped into a while loop
- I read the filename into a variable named `file`
- I use the conditional command `[[` and the `-f` operator to see that the file exists.
- If it does exist, the command after the  `&&` operator is executed, otherwise if the file does not exist, the command after the `||` operator is executed.
- Finally, I print the output in the OP's desired format.